# Can we write integration tests for cytoscape with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, cytoscape

Since Cytoscape renders the graph on canvas, I am assuming it would be harder to write tests. I am looking for a way i can write integration tests(not e2e tests) for Cytoscape.

- Front end library: React JS
- Testing library: React-testing-library

Looking for a solution to test out the functionalities that come along with Cytoscape

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this question. I have RTL tests that are rendering a Cytoscape graph into view, but all my tests fail with this error coming from react-cytoscapejs@2.0.0: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')`